# Copying to newsheet only with values from column with "Y"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have this working code that gets the value from "sheet1" column C to set it as sheet name and make a new worksheet and copies the "testscript" sheet.

My problem is I only need to copy that has the column value with "Y".

Here is my code:

```
Dim rcell As Range
Dim Background As Worksheet
Set Background = ActiveSheet

For Each rcell In Range("C2:C500")
   If rcell.Value <> "" Then
        For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)
           If LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) = LCase(rcell) Then
              MsgBox "This sheet already exists!"
              Exit Sub
           End If
        Next
        Sheets("TestScript").Copy After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = rcell.Value
   End If
Next rcell
```

Comment: Replace `If rcell.Value <> "" Then` with `If rcell.Value <> "" And Instr(rcell.Value, "Y") > 0 Then` and it will only enter the `IF` when the value "Y" is in the string.

Comment: doesn't work, column J has value "Y"  and "N" , I only need to copy the rows with "Y"

Comment: Well you didn't mention that did you ^^. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim rcell As Range
Dim Background As Worksheet
Set Background = ActiveSheet

For Each rcell In Range("C2:C500")
   'if rcell has value and same row column J is equal to "Y"
   If rcell.Value <> "" And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rcell.Row, 10).Value = "Y" Then
        For rep = 1 To (Worksheets.Count)
           If LCase(Sheets(rep).Name) = LCase(rcell) Then
              MsgBox "This sheet already exists!"
              Exit Sub
           End If
        Next
        Sheets("TestScript").Copy After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = rcell.Value
   End If
Next rcell
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: Please accept the answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: @SJR ... _And he was never seem again_ ^^

Comment: Tough luck, I fear you may be right. Have a vote from me in lieu.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim rcell As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1") ' reference your "source" sheet for subsequent range explicit qualification
        For Each rcell In .Range("C2:C500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop through wanted range not empty cells with "constant" (i.e. not formulas) values
           If UCase(.Cells(rcell.Row, 10)).Value = "Y" Then ' check current cell row column J value
                If Not IsSheetThere(rcell.Value) Then 'check there's no sheet named after current cell value
                    Sheets("TestScript").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = rcell.Value
                End If
           End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function IsSheetThere(shtName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next 'avoid any error at following line to stop the routine
    IsSheetThere = Worksheets(shtName).Name = shtName 'try getting a sheet with the passed name. this will throw an error if no sheet is found with that name 
End Function
```

Comment: sorry I'm still working at it, let me try this one and i'll get back on you guys, really big thanks for this. :)